# can we code time in text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to code time `HH:MM:SS` using text widget?
I know we can do this with label widget. My code deals with text widget and want to display time at any corner on the TKinter  window. 
If possible how to delete and insert the text using label widgets. Text widget has the following methods default.

```
delete(startindex [,endindex])
```

This method deletes a specific character or a range of text.

```
insert(index [,string]...)
```

This method inserts strings at the specified index location.
 In my code the text has to be deleted and inserted all the time.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete from `1.0` to `end`.

```
import datetime

text.delete('1.0', 'end')
text.insert('end', datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')) # text.insert('end', label['text'])
```

---

```
label['text'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

---

Display Entry on bottom right

```
import datetime
from Tkinter import * # from tkinter import *   # Python 3.x

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)

entry = Entry(frame)
entry.pack(side=RIGHT)
entry.insert(END, datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
root.mainloop()
```

---

```
def __init__(self):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    self.geometry("1360x750")
    frameLabel = tk.Frame(self)
    self.text = tk.Text(frameLabel)
    frameLabel.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)
    self.text.pack(side=RIGHT)
    self.text.insert('end', 'TEST')
    self.queue = Queue.Queue()
    thread = SerialThread(self.queue)
    thread.start()
    self.process_serial()
```

---

**UPDATE2**

```
import datetime
from Tkinter import * # from tkinter import *   # Python 3.x

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)

label = Label(frame)
label.pack(side=RIGHT)
label['text'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: my exact dought is: my code is on text widget, but i want to change the code to  label widget to use anchor option. On my requirement i need to delete and insert text on the tkinter window. I think there is no option for delete and insert the text in label widget.

Comment: thanks, the first code is working, but i need the time to be displayed on bottom right of the window

Comment: thank you sir,i tried this in my code and could not succeed.If i send my code, can you please show me how to display time on window at bottom right.

Comment: The received data prints on frame using text widget, in text widget there is no option of printing received data at center of window.so i decided to change my code from using text widget to label widget. The label widget has default is anchor=CENTER, which centers the text in the available space. then after i want clock to display on bottom right. please help me , i am new to python.

Comment: @vaasu, Check added code. (I updated `App.__init__` in your code).

Comment: @vaasu, Can you sketch what you want and upload it somewhere?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33825/discussion-between-vaasu-and-falsetru)

Comment: I changed my code from using text widget to label widget. now i want a timer to be displayed on bottom right on the window for my code. if possible please  help me.

Comment: thank you, i understood the code, but i am confused how to achieve in my code, i sended my new code in our discussion. please help me to display time in my code.

Comment: @vaasu, Do it yourself.